# JavaScript array length is showing 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, global-variables

I am facing a weird problem while dynamically fetching LatLng for an address using geocode. I have declared a global array for store the latLng values for the addresses. After storing data to that array when i console log the value of that array, it shows the values perfectly. But when i console log the value of that array length, it shows 0. Everything seems a little bit weird to me. Can't understand what is the exact problem in my code.

Here is the HTML code used to fetched all the location.

```
<div id="locations" class="col-sm-4">
        <fieldset>
        <legend class="section">Redemption Locations (<?php echo count($locations); ?>)</legend>
        <div id="stats_div" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 335px;">
            <?php foreach($locations as $location): ?>
                <div class="stats" data-id="<?php echo $location->address; ?>">
                    <span class="stat">
                        <strong><?= $location->label ? $location->label : $location->name; ?></strong>
                        <br>
                        <?php echo $location->address; ?>
                        <br>
                        <?php echo $location->phone_number; ?>
                    </span>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

The locations are looking like "25 Regina Street South, Waterloo, ON, Canada"

Here is the JS code for showing the map with location markers.

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var addresses = [];
/*var locations = [
    [43.4643342, -80.52126329999999],
    [43.6331368, -79.42370740000001]
];*/
var locations = [];

function getAddress() {
    var count = $("#locations").find(".stats").length;
    for (var i=0; i<count; i++)
        addresses.push($("#locations .stats:eq('"+i+"')").attr('data-id'));
}

function storeLatLng(lat, lng) {
    var newarr = [];
    newarr.push(lat, lng);
    locations.push(newarr);

    console.log('Array Length: '+locations.length);
}

function getLatLong() {
    getAddress();
    var i;
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    for (i in addresses) {
        var address = addresses[i];
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                storeLatLng(lat, lng);
            }
        });
    }
}

function initializeMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: {lat: 53, lng: -92.220885},
        scrollwheel: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });



    var
        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(),
        marker = '';

    getLatLong();

    console.log(locations);
    console.log(locations.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: locations[i][0], lng: locations[i][1]},
            map: map
        });

        bounds.extend(marker.position);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    initializeMap();
});
```

To check the value of the locations array, just put a console log before the loop and in the loop. output of locations array is perfect but the output of array length is 0. I can't understand why it's showing 0 as all the values of the array seem perfect to me. When i put the static value on that array(which is comment out in the code). It shows both the array values and the array length perfectly.

So, my **problem** is about global array named `locations` . If you guys check carefully, I have put console log three times in my code. One is in `storeLatLng()` and other two is in `initializeMap()`. In the `storeLatLng()` function, it prints value perfectly. In the `initializeMap()`, First console lg prints the values o the `locations` array. It seems perfect. But immediate after that line, when i console log the length of that array, it shows 0. or better understanding, i attach the console log screenshots.

[image: Image of console log]

Comment: Geocoding is asynchronous.

Comment: @geocodezip, i have edited my question, Check if it's duplicate or not. I think my problem is different.

Comment: It is a duplicate.  The geocoder is asynchronous, you are processing the array **before** the asynchronous callback functions run (when it is empty).

Comment: @geocodezip, Ok. One question arise in my mind. Then how it prints all the value of the array when i `console.log(locations);` ?

Comment: When do you do the `console.log(locations)` that displays all the values?

Comment: @geocodezip, in the `initializeMap()` function. I have put both `console.log(locations)` and `console.log(locations.length)`. `console.log(locations)` prints value perfectly. I have attached my console log screenshot with the updated question.

Comment: You mean the one that says array length in initializeMap: 0?

Comment: @geocodezip, yes. `console.log(locations)` shows all the values perfectly but `console.log(locations.length)` shows 0.